# You don't have permission to access /pgadmin4 on this server

Tags: linux, centos7, pgadmin-4

I have installed pgadmin4 on Centos 7 and this message appears when I try to execute from browser.  http://168.232.167.7/pgadmin4    Thank for help.

Comment: It seems like restriction on the web server